# Android ListViewAnimations - Item can not be swapped in DynamicListView

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop

I am using the drag and drop feature in DynamicListView to rearrange the order of items in a list.

It is working fine, except that swapping items with the next one in the list does not work. I can only drag an items at least two positions, e.g from position 1 to 3, but not from 1 to 2.

Fragment:

```
    mDynamicListView.enableDragAndDrop();
    mDynamicListView.setDraggableManager(new TouchViewDraggableManager(R.id.icon));
```

Adapter

```
@Override
public void swapItems(final int positionOne, final int positionTwo) {
    HMObject firstItem = objects.set(positionOne, getItem(positionTwo));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    objects.set(positionTwo, firstItem);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I posted an answer. This is my first time using DynamicListView. Are you using multiple UI elements in your Listview layout?

Comment: Where is enableDragAndDrop() from? Where is override swapItems() defined?

Comment: DynamicListView is part of the ListViewAnimations library: https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Answer (score 1):

Using your sample code, I suggest:

```
public void swapItems(final int positionOne, final int positionTwo) {
   HMObject firstItem = getItem(positionOne);

   objects.set(positionOne, getItem(positionTwo));
   objects.set(positionTwo, firstItem);

   notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: The main difference is the assignment of `firstItem`.